# I lose my settings of labels after switching between two windows

Tags: python, pyqt5

I try to use now classes with PyQt5 after searching and googling the whole last week.

I have two windows. One is MainWindow and the other one is PrefWindow.
On each GUI there are two buttons and a label with a text in it.
With the first button I can change the label text and its background color.

With the second button I change the GUI and go to PrefWindow

The same is on the other GUI, PrefWindow.
I can change the Text and the background color of the label and with the second button
I go back to the MainWindow.

The problem is that the changes on the MainWindow are gone after comming back from PrefWindow.
I tried to save the text and the background color of the label of each window
but it crashes with the following error message below that QLabel has been deleted. Why does it crash?

Error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/m.owzar/PycharmProjects/Relais_Tester/Question.py", line
> 132, in ChangeToMainWindow MainWindow().lbl_1.setText(lab_text_1)
> RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QLabel has been deleted
> <class 'RuntimeError'> wrapped C/C++ object of type QLabel has been
> deleted <traceback object at 0x044DA0C8> Process finished with exit
> code 1

My code is as below:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

lab_text_1 = ''
lab_bg_color_1 = ''

lab_text_2 = ''
lab_bg_color_2 = ''

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__( self ):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle("Saving Window status")
        
        self.createMainWindow()

    def createMainWindow( self ):

        self.vbox_1 = QVBoxLayout()

        self.lbl_1 = QLabel('Label 1 Init')
        self.lbl_1.move(50, 50)
        self.lbl_1.setStyleSheet('font-size: 13pt; color: blue; background-color:lightgreen; font-weight: bold;')


        self.btnChange_1 = QPushButton("Change Label Text")
        self.btnChange_1.setFixedSize(200, 50)
        self.btnChange_1.clicked.connect(self.chaneLabelText_1)
        self.btnChange_1.setStyleSheet('font-size: 12pt; color: blue; background-color:lightcyan; font-weight: bold;')

        self.btnSettings = QPushButton("Settings")
        self.btnSettings.setFixedSize(200, 50)
        self.btnSettings.clicked.connect(self.ChangeToPrefWindow)
        self.btnSettings.setStyleSheet('font-size: 12pt; color: blue; background-color:lightcyan; font-weight: bold;')

        self.vbox_1.addWidget(self.lbl_1)
        self.vbox_1.addWidget(self.btnChange_1)
        self.vbox_1.addWidget(self.btnSettings)

        self.setLayout(self.vbox_1)

    def chaneLabelText_1(self):
        print('Label Text before: ' + self.lbl_1.text())
        self.lbl_1.setText('Labl 1 is new.\nIts Background color is also new!')
        print('Label Text after:  ' + self.lbl_1.text())

        lbl_1_bg_color = self.lbl_1.palette().color(QPalette.Base).name()
        print('Label Background color before:  ' + lbl_1_bg_color)

        self.lbl_1.setStyleSheet('font-size: 16pt; color: blue; background-color:cyan; font-weight: bold;')
        
        lbl_1_bg_color = self.lbl_1.palette().color(QPalette.Base).name()
        print('Label Background color after:  ' + lbl_1_bg_color)

    # Go to PrefWindow
    #####################################################################
    def ChangeToPrefWindow(self):
        lab_text_1 = self.lbl_1.text()
        lab_bg_color_1 = self.lbl_1.palette().color(QPalette.Base).name()

        # PrefWindow().lbl_2.setText(lab_text_2)
        # PrefWindow().lab_bg_color_2.setStyleSheet(f'font-size: 16pt; color: blue; background-color:{lab_bg_color_2}; font-weight: bold;')

        self.cams = PrefWindow()
        self.cams.show()
        self.close()


class PrefWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__( self ):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle("Settings Window")

        self.createPrefWindow()

    def createPrefWindow( self ):

        self.vbox_2 = QVBoxLayout()

        self.lbl_2 = QLabel('Label 2 Init')
        self.lbl_2.move(50, 50)
        self.lbl_2.setStyleSheet('font-size: 13pt; color: blue; background-color:lightgreen; font-weight: bold;')

        self.btnChange_2 = QPushButton("Change Label Text")
        self.btnChange_2.setFixedSize(200, 50)
        self.btnChange_2.clicked.connect(self.chaneLabelText_2)
        self.btnChange_2.setStyleSheet('font-size: 12pt; color: blue; background-color:lightcyan; font-weight: bold;')

        self.btnSave = QPushButton("Save and Quit")
        self.btnSave.setFixedSize(200, 50)
        self.btnSave.setStyleSheet('font-size: 12pt; color: blue; background-color:lightcyan; font-weight: bold;'
            )
        self.btnSave.clicked.connect(self.ChangeToMainWindow)

        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.lbl_2)
        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.btnChange_2)
        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.btnSave)

        self.setLayout(self.vbox_2)


    def chaneLabelText_2(self):
        print('Label Text before: ' + self.lbl_2.text())
        self.lbl_2.setText('Labl 2 is new. \nIts Background color is also new!')
        print('Label Text after:  ' + self.lbl_2.text())

        lbl_2_bg_color = self.lbl_2.palette().color(QPalette.Base).name()
        print('Label Background color before:  ' + lbl_2_bg_color)

        self.lbl_2.setStyleSheet('font-size: 16pt; color: blue; background-color:cyan; font-weight: bold;')
        
        lbl_2_bg_color = self.lbl_2.palette().color(QPalette.Base).name()
        print('Label Background color after:  ' + lbl_2_bg_color)

    # Go to MainWindow
    #####################################################################
    def ChangeToMainWindow( self ):
        lab_text_2 = self.lbl_2.text()
        lab_bg_color_2 = self.lbl_2.palette().color(QPalette.Base).name()

        MainWindow().lbl_1.setText(lab_text_1)
        MainWindow().lab_bg_color_1.setStyleSheet(f'font-size: 16pt; color: blue; background-color:{lab_bg_color_1}; font-weight: bold;')

        self.cams = MainWindow()
        self.cams.show()
        self.close()

def main():
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    sys._excepthook = sys.excepthook

    def exception_hook( exctype, value, traceback ):
        print(exctype, value, traceback)
        sys._excepthook(exctype, value, traceback)
        sys.exit(1)

    sys.excepthook = exception_hook

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create `self.cams = MainWindow()` every time.

When creating the `self.cams = PrefWindow(self)` object, pass a reference to the `MainWindow` object.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

#lab_text_1 = ''
#lab_bg_color_1 = ''
#lab_text_2 = ''
#lab_bg_color_2 = ''


class PrefWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__( self, parent=None ):                                    # + parent
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent                                              # + parent

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle("Settings Window")
        self.createPrefWindow()
        
        self.lab_text_2 = ''                                              # +++
        self.lab_bg_color_2 = ''                                          # +++

    def createPrefWindow( self ):
        self.vbox_2 = QVBoxLayout()

        self.lbl_2 = QLabel('Label 2 Init')
        self.lbl_2.move(50, 50)
        self.lbl_2.setStyleSheet('font-size: 13pt; color: blue; background-color:lightgreen; font-weight: bold;')

        self.btnChange_2 = QPushButton("Change Label Text")
        self.btnChange_2.setFixedSize(200, 50)
        self.btnChange_2.clicked.connect(self.chaneLabelText_2)
        self.btnChange_2.setStyleSheet('font-size: 12pt; color: blue; background-color:lightcyan; font-weight: bold;')

        self.btnSave = QPushButton("Save and Quit")
        self.btnSave.setFixedSize(200, 50)
        self.btnSave.setStyleSheet(
            'font-size: 12pt; color: blue; background-color:lightcyan; font-weight: bold;'
        )
        self.btnSave.clicked.connect(self.ChangeToMainWindow)

        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.lbl_2)
        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.btnChange_2)
        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.btnSave)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox_2)

    def chaneLabelText_2(self):
        print('Label Text before: ' + self.lbl_2.text())
        self.lbl_2.setText('Labl 2 is new. \nIts Background color is also new!')
        print('Label Text after:  ' + self.lbl_2.text())

        lbl_2_bg_color = self.lbl_2.palette().color(QPalette.Base).name()
        print('Label Background color before:  ' + lbl_2_bg_color)

        self.lbl_2.setStyleSheet('font-size: 16pt; color: blue; background-color:cyan; font-weight: bold;')
        
        lbl_2_bg_color = self.lbl_2.palette().color(QPalette.Base).name()
        print('Label Background color after:  ' + lbl_2_bg_color)

    # Go to MainWindow
    #####################################################################
    def ChangeToMainWindow( self ):
        self.lab_text_2 = self.lbl_2.text()
        self.lab_bg_color_2 = self.lbl_2.palette().color(QPalette.Base).name()

###      MainWindow --> self.parent
#        MainWindow().lbl_1.setText(lab_text_1)
        self.parent.lbl_1.setText(self.lab_text_2)                       # ? lab_text_2
        self.parent.lbl_1.setStyleSheet(
            f'font-size: 16pt; color: blue; background-color:{self.lab_bg_color_2}; font-weight: bold;')

# -       self.cams = MainWindow()
        self.parent.show()
        self.hide()
        
        
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__( self ):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle("Saving Window status")
        self.createMainWindow()
# +
        self.cams = PrefWindow(self)                                   # +++ + self
        self.lab_text_1 = ''                                           # +++
        self.lab_bg_color_1 = ''                                       # +++ 

    def createMainWindow( self ):
        self.vbox_1 = QVBoxLayout()

        self.lbl_1 = QLabel('Label 1 Init')
        self.lbl_1.move(50, 50)
        self.lbl_1.setStyleSheet('font-size: 13pt; color: blue; background-color:lightgreen; font-weight: bold;')

        self.btnChange_1 = QPushButton("Change Label Text")
        self.btnChange_1.setFixedSize(200, 50)
        self.btnChange_1.clicked.connect(self.chaneLabelText_1)
        self.btnChange_1.setStyleSheet('font-size: 12pt; color: blue; background-color:lightcyan; font-weight: bold;')

        self.btnSettings = QPushButton("Settings")
        self.btnSettings.setFixedSize(200, 50)
        self.btnSettings.clicked.connect(self.ChangeToPrefWindow)
        self.btnSettings.setStyleSheet('font-size: 12pt; color: blue; background-color:lightcyan; font-weight: bold;')

        self.vbox_1.addWidget(self.lbl_1)
        self.vbox_1.addWidget(self.btnChange_1)
        self.vbox_1.addWidget(self.btnSettings)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox_1)

    def chaneLabelText_1(self):
        print('Label Text before: ' + self.lbl_1.text())
        self.lbl_1.setText('Labl 1 is new.\nIts Background color is also new!')
        print('Label Text after:  ' + self.lbl_1.text())

        lbl_1_bg_color = self.lbl_1.palette().color(QPalette.Base).name()
        print('Label Background color before:  ' + lbl_1_bg_color)

        self.lbl_1.setStyleSheet('font-size: 16pt; color: blue; background-color:cyan; font-weight: bold;')
        
        lbl_1_bg_color = self.lbl_1.palette().color(QPalette.Base).name()
        print('Label Background color after:  ' + lbl_1_bg_color)


    # Go to PrefWindow
    #####################################################################
    def ChangeToPrefWindow(self):
        self.lab_text_1 = self.lbl_1.text()
        self.lab_bg_color_1 = self.lbl_1.palette().color(QPalette.Base).name()

        # PrefWindow().lbl_2.setText(lab_text_2)
        # PrefWindow().lab_bg_color_2.setStyleSheet(f'font-size: 16pt; color: blue; background-color:{lab_bg_color_2}; font-weight: bold;')

#        self.cams = PrefWindow()
        self.cams.show()
        self.hide()                                                   # close()


def main():
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    sys._excepthook = sys.excepthook

    def exception_hook( exctype, value, traceback ):
        print(exctype, value, traceback)
        sys._excepthook(exctype, value, traceback)
        sys.exit(1)

    sys.excepthook = exception_hook

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

below is my modified code.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

colors = ['yellow', 'cyan', 'orange', 'white', 'magenta', 'lightgreen', ]
I = 0

class PrefWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__( self, parent=None ):   # + parent
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent             # + parent

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle("Settings Window")
        self.createPrefWindow()

        self.lab_text_2 = ''              # +++
        self.lab_bg_color_2 = ''          # +++

    def createPrefWindow( self ):
        self.vbox_2 = QVBoxLayout()

        self.lbl_2 = QLabel('Label 2 Init\nOn the Settings Window')
        self.lbl_2.move(50, 50)
        self.lbl_2.setStyleSheet('font-size: 13pt; color: blue; background-color:lightgreen; font-weight: bold;')

        self.btnChange_2 = QPushButton("Change Label Text")
        self.btnChange_2.setFixedSize(200, 50)
        self.btnChange_2.clicked.connect(self.chaneLabelText_2)
        self.btnChange_2.setStyleSheet('font-size: 12pt; color: blue; background-color:lightcyan; font-weight: bold;')

        self.btnSave = QPushButton("Save and Quit")
        self.btnSave.setFixedSize(200, 50)
        self.btnSave.setStyleSheet('font-size: 12pt; color: blue; background-color:lightcyan; font-weight: bold;')
        self.btnSave.clicked.connect(self.ChangeToMainWindow)

        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.lbl_2)
        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.btnChange_2)
        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.btnSave)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox_2)

    def chaneLabelText_2( self ):
        global I

        print('Label Text before: ' + self.lbl_2.text())
        self.lbl_2.setText(f'I = {I % 6}\nLabl 2 is new. \nIts Background color is also new!\nOn the Settings Window')
        print('Label Text after:  ' + self.lbl_2.text())

        lbl_2_bg_color = self.lbl_2.palette().color(QPalette.Base).name()
        print('Label Background color before:  ' + lbl_2_bg_color)

        COLOR = colors[I % 6]
        self.lbl_2.setStyleSheet(f'font-size: 16pt; color: blue; background-color:{COLOR}; font-weight: bold;')
        I += 1

        lbl_2_bg_color = self.lbl_2.palette().color(QPalette.Base).name()
        print('Label Background color after:  ' + lbl_2_bg_color)

    # Go to MainWindow
    #####################################################################
    def ChangeToMainWindow( self ):
        self.lab_text_2 = self.lbl_2.text()
        self.lab_bg_color_2 = self.lbl_2.palette().color(QPalette.Base).name()

        # self.parent.lbl_1.setText(self.lab_text_1)
        # self.parent.lbl_1.setStyleSheet(f'font-size: 16pt; color: blue; background-color:{self.lab_bg_color_1}; font-weight: bold;')

        self.parent.show()
        self.hide()

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__( self ):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle("Saving Window status")
        self.createMainWindow()
        # +
        self.cams = PrefWindow(self)      # +++ + self
        self.lab_text_1 = ''              # +++
        self.lab_bg_color_1 = ''          # +++

    def createMainWindow( self ):
        self.vbox_1 = QVBoxLayout()

        self.lbl_1 = QLabel('Label 1 Init\nOn the MainWindow')
        self.lbl_1.move(50, 50)
        self.lbl_1.setStyleSheet('font-size: 13pt; color: blue; background-color:yellow; font-weight: bold;')

        self.btnChange_1 = QPushButton("Change Label Text")
        self.btnChange_1.setFixedSize(200, 50)
        self.btnChange_1.clicked.connect(self.chaneLabelText_1)
        self.btnChange_1.setStyleSheet('font-size: 12pt; color: blue; background-color:lightcyan; font-weight: bold;')

        self.btnSettings = QPushButton("Settings")
        self.btnSettings.setFixedSize(200, 50)
        self.btnSettings.clicked.connect(self.ChangeToPrefWindow)
        self.btnSettings.setStyleSheet('font-size: 12pt; color: blue; background-color:lightcyan; font-weight: bold;')

        self.vbox_1.addWidget(self.lbl_1)
        self.vbox_1.addWidget(self.btnChange_1)
        self.vbox_1.addWidget(self.btnSettings)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox_1)

    def chaneLabelText_1( self ):
        print('Label Text before: ' + self.lbl_1.text())
        self.lbl_1.setText('Labl 1 is new.\nIts Background color is also new!\nOn the MainWindow')
        print('Label Text after:  ' + self.lbl_1.text())

        lbl_1_bg_color = self.lbl_1.palette().color(QPalette.Base).name()
        print('Label Background color before:  ' + lbl_1_bg_color)

        self.lbl_1.setStyleSheet('font-size: 16pt; color: blue; background-color:cyan; font-weight: bold;')

        lbl_1_bg_color = self.lbl_1.palette().color(QPalette.Base).name()
        print('Label Background color after:  ' + lbl_1_bg_color)

    # Go to PrefWindow
    #####################################################################
    def ChangeToPrefWindow( self ):
        self.lab_text_1 = self.lbl_1.text()
        self.lab_bg_color_1 = self.lbl_1.palette().color(QPalette.Base).name()

        # self.parent.lbl_2.setText(self.lab_text_2)
        # PrefWindow().lbl_2.setStyleSheet(f'font-size: 16pt; color: blue; background-color:{PrefWindow().lab_bg_color_2}; font-weight: bold;')

        self.cams.show()
        self.hide()  # close()

def main():
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    sys._excepthook = sys.excepthook

    def exception_hook( exctype, value, traceback ):
        print(exctype, value, traceback)
        sys._excepthook(exctype, value, traceback)
        sys.exit(1)

    sys.excepthook = exception_hook

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I don't know why my post was deleted by an administrator.
I sent the corrected version of your code as an answer, but after three hours it was deleted.
I don't know which bad rule I have used

Comment: I tried to understand your modified code and have modified also to get running as I wanted.
I've also added 6 colors to the changeLabelText_2 method to see if the changes are really persistent when I come back to the PrefWindow back. It seems to be that it works somehow
The thing is that it works only in one direction.
I tried to add the same approach as you did in the PrefWindow to put in the MainWindow to preserve the status of the label attributes, but didn't work.

Comment: My added approach didn’t work because I think that it is not allowed to make MainWindow to be a sub class of the PrefWindow if the PrefWindow was a sub class of the MainWindow before.
Because in my real project I have on my Settings Window (PrefWindow) lots of variables to be set and used on the MainWindow, what is the best approach to manage all the setting values to save in an .INI file and each time load this file on starting the program.
And if any changes are maid they should be taken to MainWindow by pressing the Save&Quit button and ignored if the Quit button is pressed.

Comment: I put the modified code again in the question area.  
If you could explain a bit the relation between the widgets, parent and children?  
I add the modified code below.  
Thanks a lot, in advance.  

Regards  
Mohsen